# ¿Cómo puedo codificar y decodificar una cadena base64?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, base64

¿Cómo devuelvo una cadena codificada en base64 dada una cadena?

¿Cómo decodifico una cadena codificada en base64 en una cadena?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**CODIFICAR**

```
public static string Base64Encode(string plainText) {
  var plainTextBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);
  return System.Convert.ToBase64String(plainTextBytes);
}
```

**DECODIFICAR**

```
public static string Base64Decode(string base64EncodedData) {
  var base64EncodedBytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(base64EncodedData);
  return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(base64EncodedBytes);
}
```

Comment: cual es el sentido de hacer la pregunta y responderla uno mismo ? deberias haber editado la pregunta y colocado la solucion o sino simplemente quitar la pregunta si le encontrarste tu mismo la respuesta

Comment: Por si alguien mas tiene la misma duda, pueda encontrar la solución, no mas, no veo el problema.

Comment: Hasta la misma pagina lo propone cuando se hace la pregunta